# Render video on white SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the fallowing code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        MediaPlayer player;
        Button playBtn;
        FrameLayout frame;
        boolean plaing = false;
        Uri uri;
        volatile boolean surfaceReady;

        boolean drawCanvas = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
            playBtn.setOnClickListener(new CKL());
            frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameForVideo);
            createSurfaceView(frame);
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setLooping(true);
            String urri = "android.resource://com.example.videoplayer/raw/id_1_l_belen";
            uri = Uri.parse(urri);
            Log.d("atf", urri);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();
            super.onPause();
        }

        private class CKL implements OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!plaing)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        player.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
                        player.setLooping(true);
                        player.prepare();
                        player.start();
                        plaing = true;
                        Log.d("atf", "Player started");
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        Error er = new Error(e);
                        throw er;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    surfaceReady = false;
                    player.stop();
                    player.reset();
                    plaing = false;
                    createSurfaceView(frame);
                }


            }

        }

        private class SurfaceCreationLisatener implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                player.setDisplay(holder);
            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

        }

        private void createSurfaceView(FrameLayout frame){
            frame.removeAllViews();
            SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCreationLisatener());        
            frame.addView(surfaceView);
        }
    }
```

Basically, i use MediaPlayer to render a video on a SurfaceView. The problem is that this SurfaceView is black, setting a background color is useless since it behaves not like an ordinary View.

Basically, i need to make this black background of the view invisible. Workarounds like making the whole surface invisible while video is not playing are not suitable for me.
I need to put the surface in a ListView and there the black surface is flashing when scrolling even if the video is playing. (Looks ugly)
I also tried to use TextureView but there is another problem:
When lunching multiple videos at a time this videos are glitching because rendering on TextureView consumes more resources.

A solution for me would be to color the SurfaceView in white so the MediaPlayer could render it's content on a white surface but i have no idea how to do this.
The following code is not working.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Canvas cnvs = holder.lockCanvas();
    cnvs.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(cnvs);
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}
```

After drawing the surface, MediaPlayer is not showing anything. It looks like its not using the surface. Why?... have no idea.

I would appreciate any coming ideas from you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this: put your surfaceview on a framelayout (it can be the one you are already using on your createSurfaceView), with another view on top of your surfaceview. This new view can be just a button with a white background (or even better, a thumbnail or a still frame of the video) and set it to the same width and height of the surfaceview. Then, in the onclick of this button you hide it to show the surfaceview and play the video.